# Why use @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-optimization

How does

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

differ from just referencing the script from html like this

```
<script src="~/bundles/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Are there any performance gains?

Comment: How do I add type=“text/css”  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662096/how-do-i-add-type-text-css-to-a-script-tag-when-using-system-web-optimization

Answer (score 300, accepted):

Bundling is all about compressing several JavaScript or stylesheets files without any formatting (also referred as minified) into a single file for saving bandwith and number of requests to load a page.

As example you could create your own bundle:

```
bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/mybundle").Include(
            "~/Resources/Core/Javascripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js",
            "~/Resources/Core/Javascripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.min.js",
            "~/Resources/Core/Javascripts/jquery.validate.min.js",
            "~/Resources/Core/Javascripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js",
            "~/Resources/Core/Javascripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js",
            "~/Resources/Core/Javascripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"))
```

And render it like this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/mybundle")
```

One more advantage of `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/mybundle")` over the native `<script src="~/bundles/mybundle" />` is that `@Scripts.Render()` will respect the `web.config` debug setting:

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true|false" />
```

If `debug="true"` then it will instead render individual script tags for each  source script, without any minification.

For stylesheets you will have to use a StyleBundle and @Styles.Render().

Instead of loading each script or style with a single request (with script or link tags), all files are compressed into a single JavaScript or stylesheet file and loaded together.

Comment: Just wondering: is there a file stored somewhere for that bundle or does it just exist in memory?

Comment: It can also be set to automatically use a CDN and fallback to local scripts if the CDN is unavailable.  It's pretty slick.

Comment: There is an additional benefit to doing this. When debugging, Scripts.Render will output each file unbundled, which makes local development much less of a pain, but in a live environment, this will output the bundled/minified result, which can lead to the performance gains as described above, but without changing any code.

Comment: In the "basic" template of MVC4 (Visual Studio), bundles are prepared in "BundleConfig.cs" (App_Start folder).

Comment: As per comment in other answer: Consider the async javascript attribute: `Scripts.RenderFormat(@"<script src=""{0}"" async></script>", "~/bundles/jquery"`

Comment: This is great because it lets you put all of the bundling for all of the pages for the entire project in one file! (dripping sarcasm)

Comment: For me another important benefit is the cache busting you get for free. If any file changes in your bundle, the view will change the src of the bundle to a new bundle so the client picks up the modified scripts on the next page load

Answer (score 52):

You can also use:

```
@Scripts.RenderFormat("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"{0}\"></script>", "~/bundles/mybundle")
```

To specify the format of your output in a scenario where you need to use Charset, Type, etc.

Comment: Also very useful for loading requirejs modules

Comment: ...or to add the `async` attribute.

Comment: `@Scripts.RenderFormat("<script type=\"text/javascript\" async src=\"{0}\"></script>", "~/bundles/mybundle")`

Comment: ... or to add the crossorigin="anonymous" attribute