# Scripts.Render() if not exists

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper, bundling-and-minification

I want the following call to render only if such call wasn't already declared in a parent view.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jQuery")
```

What's the best way to do so?

Comment: checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12192646/why-use-scripts-render-bundles-jquery

Comment: generally you should design your bundles so they dont have overlaps, id suggest having one bundle for the main page and one for the child view

Comment: additionaly if you are loading jquery related libraries these should be added at the end of the page in most cases, so the master page/layout is the best place to do this.

Comment: This already is at the layout page, it's however an area local layout. It needs to detect if the parent layout already defines these things. I need the check at runtime. In short, yes I'm aware there're workarounds, but I want this to behave exactly as I described it. Is there a way to do so out of the box? I can run custom code if I have to, but prefer to work with the framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
<script>
    if (!window.jQuery) {
        document.write('<script src="@BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Scripts/jQuery")">\x3C/script>');
    }
</script>
```

This is essentially the same logic used when one includes jQuery from a CDN, and then has a local reference fallback if the CDN delivery failed.

Comment: Yes this seems like one possible solution. Thank you!